# JSP supplying information to a Angular 6+ UI

Tags: java, angular, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am starting my career in programming and I have being trying to learn as much as I can, specially in "new" technologies as Angular 2+, although I like a lot more working on the back-end.

I am currently working in a company  that has 4 main applications all running using Java EE 7 in a JBoss application server. The applications have a user interface with is currently based in Java Server Pages (JSP) and Java Server Faces (JSF) (mainly using PrimeFaces framework). My project is related to the migration of the User Interface from those "horrible" xhtml JSF pages to something like Angular 6+.

Needless to say that this this transition should happen with minimum changes to the back end. However, in the way the Back end was originally conceived, the back end is not RESTful (no REST API). So, it is all based on Beans, which makes the back end to be closely tight to the front end, making scalebility an issue.

All that being said, considering that creating such RESTful service, although not completely off the table, is not an option now, I have the following questions:

1) Is it possible to 'feed' the data to my Angular UI using a JSP !? I did some research on the topic, and it seems it is somehow possible.

2) Considering it is possible to use the JSP pages, how much of Angular "great tools and functionality" I would loose in this process (routing, two-way-binding, service injection, etc)?

It would be great to have some unbiased opinion, since I know where the people at my company stand on that issue (they would prefer to not spending the time creating the REST API at this time) and I know where I stand (I would rather create the service, since it would be a great learning oportunity for me). Still, facing the challenges of a real world application, I would like to know the community opinion.

Thank you for the help,

Answer (score 0):

*biased opinion, even though you asked for a non biased one*

I'm not an authority on JSP, but from what I know, these are server side templates rendered on the backend. If this is the case then you cannot use this with angular. Maybe you can make it work somehow by extending the webpack config and custom plugins which load the .jsp files, but you will definitely lose either the AOT performance from angular or the dynamic nature from JSP. And besides that, angular is moving to all AOT anyways.

My suggestion is the same as yours, write a RESTful service. It shouldn't take too long, because the requests/responses are already available. Just make sure to follow to correct REST guidelines.

Then create the angular app based on the templates from jsp. I suppose you can copy these one on one, and change the syntax from jsp to angular, and obtain the necessary data from the REST api and populate these in your template

Comment: Thank you for your response (biased or not, :- ) ). I also agree that the best solution would be creating the RESTful service. Mixing JSP and Angular would only generate just some convoluted code.